# Google Drive API proxy exception 407

Tags: c#, google-api

Im trying to download files from google disk.
Auth Class:

```
internal static class Perm_AppData
{
    private static string[] scopes = { DriveService.Scope.DriveFile };
    private static DriveService service = Autorization();
    internal static DriveService Service { get { return service; } }

    private static DriveService Autorization()
    {
        UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream = GetCliSecStream())
        {
            credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(auth, true)).Result;
        }

        return new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = applicationName
        });
    }

    private static Stream GetCliSecStream()
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream);
        writer.Write(uSec);
        writer.Flush();
        stream.Position = 0;
        return stream;
    }
}
```

After that, I chose an account and confirmed the rights of the application. Next is the request to download the file

```
internal static MemoryStream DownloadFile(string fileId = null, string fileName = null)
{
    using (new Watcher($"Download {fileName} {fileId}"))
    {
        GetRequest request = null;
        if (fileId != null)
        {
            request = service.Files.Get(fileId);
        }
        else
        {
            if (fileName != null)
            {
                request = service.Files.Get(ViewDrive(SearchParameter.name, new string[] { fileName }).First().Id);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("You need at least one not null parameter to download");
            }
        }

        request.Fields = "id, name";
        var fileMemoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        request.Download(fileMemoryStream);
        return fileMemoryStream;
    }
}
```

Downloading the file throws an exception (System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Requires proxy authentication):

> Error: System.TypeInitializationException: Инициализатор типа
>   "Updater.UnDloadAP I" выдал исключение. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: Инициализатор типа 
>   "Updater.Perm_AppData" выдал исключение. --->
>   System.AggregateException: Произо шла одна или несколько ошибок. --->
>   System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Произо шла ошибка при отправке
>   запроса. ---> System.Net.WebException: Удаленный сервер возвратил
>   ошибку: (407) Требуется аутентификация посредника.    в
>   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Tra nsportContext& context)    в
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult
>   ar)
>
> --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---    в
>   Google.Apis.Http.ConfigurableMessageHandler.d__55.MoveNext()
>   --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение  ---    в
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    в
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNoti
>   fication(Task task)    в
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests.TokenRequestExtenstions.d__0
>   .MoveNext()
>   --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение  ---    в
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    в
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNoti
>   fication(Task task)    в
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.d__35.
>   MoveNext()
>   --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение  ---    в
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    в
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNoti
>   fication(Task task)    в
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows.AuthorizationCodeFlow.d__30.MoveNext()
>   --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение  ---    в
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    в
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNoti
>   fication(Task task)    в
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.d__8.
>   MoveNext()
>   --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение  ---    в
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    в
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNoti
>   fication(Task task)    в
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__4.M
>   oveNext()
>   --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение  ---    в
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    в
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNoti
>   fication(Task task)    в
>   Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.d__1.M
>   oveNext()    --- Конец трассировки внутреннего стека исключений ---
>   в System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean
>   includeTaskCanceledE xceptions)    в
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
>   waitCompletionNotificat ion)    в
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()    в
>   Updater.Perm_AppData.Autorization() в C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual
>   Studio  Projects\SMNote\Updater\Classes\API\Perm_AppData.cs:строка 27

I need something like:

```
WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
```

I do not get an error if I connect to the Internet without a proxy
Post updated #1:
The following code normally passes through the proxy

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

Therefore, I believe that you need to somehow manually add a proxy to the request for google drive

Post updated #2:
The following code normally passes through the proxy

```
internal static void DoIt()
{
    try
    {
        var t = DownloadPageAsync();
        Console.WriteLine("Downloading page...");
        Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
    }
}

private static async Task<string> DownloadPageAsync()
{
    var proxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;
    proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler()
    {
        Proxy = proxy
    };
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler))
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("https://mail.ru"))
        {
            using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
            {
                string result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return result.Substring(0, 50);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "I need something like" - so what happens if you do that? I would *expect* `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` to be used by default.

Comment: Post updated #1

Comment: You still haven't said what happens if you set `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy` and its credentials though. That's what I'd expect our code to use implicitly, via `HttpClientHandler`

Comment: I do not understand your question. I described the exception that throws away my Google Drive solution. The code in update # 1 correctly returns the response of the request

Comment: I'm saying that you've got a line of code `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;` and you've said "I need something like" - but there's no indication about what happens if you try *that exact line of code*.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I answered your question in update # 1

Comment: No, you didn't. You showed something entirely different, which was modifying the proxy for a manually-created `WebRequest`. You haven't said what happens with the Google Drive API code you showed earlier, if you add the line modifying `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials`. They're not the same thing at all.

Comment: 'WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy' Was an abstract example. I do not know how to add proxy settings to the solution. I apologize if I misled you

Comment: Well have you tried `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;`? That's modifying the default proxy in exactly the same way as you're modifying the manually-created web request... if you've got an idea, you should try it, basically...

Comment: Could you show me an example plz

Comment: That *is* the example. I'm not sure what more I can say... put that line of code at the start of your application and try running it...

Comment: `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);` in simple request application works fine. But not in Google Drive app. I tried to request authentication and downloading a file with this option, but without success

Comment: I suggest you forget about Drive for the moment, and experiment with how to get the proxy to work with a simple HttpClient request - that's what the library uses under the hood, rather than WebRequest.

Comment: Post updated #2

Comment: The code in upd # 2 works with http:// google.ru and with https:// mail.ru for example. If I try to make a request to https:// google.ru, proxy exceptions occur. I do not understand why this happens

Comment: That's very interesting - all the API requests will be via HTTPS. You probably want to ask your local system administrator about how your proxy supports HTTPS. (Does that work with `WebRequest`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Drive code works fine. Problem is that i have limited access to Proxy. Thanks toJon Skeet that helped to find the problem